# Python error importing dateutil

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-dateutil

I try to execute marathon-lb.py and it throws the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./marathon_lb.py", line 46, in <module>
    import dateutil.parser
ImportError: No module named 'dateutil'
```

I just install python with apt and with pip.
I have run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install python-dateutil
```

I compile the script with: python -m py_compile script.py

python application:

```
from operator import attrgetter
from shutil import move
from tempfile import mkstemp
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from six.moves.urllib import parse
from itertools import cycle
from common import *
from config import *
from lrucache import *
from utils import *

import argparse
import json
import logging
import os
import os.path
import stat
import re
import requests
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys
import time
import dateutil.parser
```

Comment: Did you also install dateutil with pip ?

Comment: Did you run `pip install python-dateutil`?

Comment: Yes I have run @BubbleHacker

Comment: @Asier and was there some kind of error or it all worked?

Comment: It throws _Requirement already satisfied_

Comment: What happens when you run `import dateutil` in Python terminal?

Comment: it imports fine @BubbleHacker

Comment: I have a feeling when it is compiled it is not able to compile the `dateutil` module. I will update when I confirm this...

Comment: Let's add some methodology here. First, install a virtualenv and see if it is possible. I believe you may not have some basic c++ compilers that Python requires for installing some packages. This problem will be more evident when you try to install a virtuanelv.

Comment: I execute `sudo apt-get install virtualenv` and the packet is not found @RicardoSilveira

Comment: It should be `pip install virtualenv` @Asier

Comment: So, the python terminal imports fine, but your script does not? Are you running different versions of python?

Comment: It install fine @GarySham

Comment: How can I verify if I am running different versions of python? @cricket_007

Comment: @Asier Run `python -V`, and also `pip -V` to check the version of pip, there are two different pip for python2 and 3.

Comment: I have pip 1.5.4 (python 2.7) and Python 2.7.6 its fine? @GarySham

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install `python-dateutil`

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: does this statement runs on python shell `import dateutil.parser` ?

Comment: Yes it runs on python shell

Comment: So is it still giving error when  you try to compile script?

Comment: There are probably multiple versions of `python-dateutil` installed. Try to issue `pip uninstall python-dateutil` several times until the prompt says there is no `python-dateutil` installed. Then, you can issue `pip install python-dateutil` again. That solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1. First thing is upgrade pip for corresponding python version (3 or 2) you have.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
pip2 install --upgrade pip
```

#### Step2.

Some times directly running command wont work since

There are probably multiple versions of `python-dateutil` installed.

1. Try to run  `pip uninstall python-dateutil`

will give below message if `python-dateutil` is already un installed.

> Cannot uninstall requirement python-dateutil, not installed

2. Then, you can run  `pip install python-dateutil` again.

#### NOTE : Directly running step2 wont work for users whose python and pip versions are not compatible.